# ZFS still writes to HDDs vdev while dataset is configure to store special for Docker

Tags: linux, docker, filesystems, zfs

I'm facing a strange behaviour when using Docker together with ZFS.

I have one pool with 2x10TB HDDs as mirror vdev and 2x250GB NVMEs as mirror for special vdev (to store metadata and datasets with small config files etc).

I decided to put my Docker Root (containers/images) in ZFS dataset using ZFS driver:

**/etc/docker/daemon.json:**

```json
{  
   "data-root": "/docker-root",  
  "storage-driver": "zfs"  
}
```

I also set the recordsize of /docker-root dataset to 32K and special_small_blocks to 128K, to make sure all files store in dataset get allocated and store in special vdev with fast NVMEs. (I understood if you set the recordsize equal or smaller than special_small_blocks, all files go to special vdev)

But the problem is that I still see quite a lot writes to HDDs vdevs when I'm starting and stopping containers. As well frequent rights while containers are running, which is not the case when I stop all containers.
I also made sure that all containers mounted volumes are mounted in config dataset that is configured the same to store all files special vdev.

The atime property is also off for datasets in the pool.

Why this is still happening even though I'm forcing all docker related files to be store in special vdev? Is this still expected or I'm missing something?

Layout of the pool:

```
NAME                                                 SIZE  ALLOC   FREE  CKPOINT  EXPANDSZ   FRAG    CAP  DEDUP    HEALTH  ALTROOT
storage-pool-01                                     9.32T  6.50T  2.82T        -         -     0%    69%  1.00x    ONLINE  -
  mirror-0                                          9.09T  6.41T  2.68T        -         -     0%  70.5%      -    ONLINE
    ata-ST10000NE000-xxxxxx_xxxxxxx1                    -      -      -        -         -      -      -      -    ONLINE
    ata-ST20000NM007D-xxxxxx_xxxxxxx2                   -      -      -        -         -      -      -      -    ONLINE
special                                                 -      -      -        -         -      -      -      -  -
  mirror-1                                           232G  91.5G   140G        -         -    29%  39.4%      -    ONLINE
    nvme-Samsung_SSD_980_PRO_250GB_xxxxxxxxxxxxxx1      -      -      -        -         -      -      -      -    ONLINE
    nvme-Samsung_SSD_980_PRO_250GB_xxxxxxxxxxxxxx2      -      -      -        -         -      -      -      -    ONLINE
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You know, docker containers might be able to write to filesystem when configured so.

Comment: I made sure all mounted to volumes that only store data in datasets that also are configure with recordsize and special_small_blocks to be store in special vdev.

Comment: You might use `lsof` to debug why it's writing at other places.